# Asp.Net Identity 3 without datastore

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I'm planning on building a web application with Asp.Net Core without local user accounts; any authentication will happen by external authentication providers using SAML2. Am I right that I won't need the Entity Framework datastore that is configured by default in the web application template (or any other persistent store, for that matter)?

I thought about implementing my own versions of the `IUserStore<TUser>` and `IRoleStore<TRole>` interfaces with some kind of in-memory data structure behind. Would that work? Anything I should be aware of? Any *caveats*?

Comment: Will your application need to store any state at all?

Comment: Only the fact that a user is logged in and the claims / entitlements he got from the authentication provider, but not persistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want persistence, then you likely don't need any membership stack at all: in this case, there's no reason to use ASP.NET Core Identity. Using the cookies middleware should be enough to achieve what you want.

Unfortunately, neither SAML2P nor WS-Fed are officially supported yet. There's a community initiative that aims at providing a SAML2 authentication middleware, but AFAIK, it's still a work in progress and is not compatible with .NET Core (it only works with ASP.NET Core on .NET Desktop): https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/tree/aspnetcore

Comment: Yes, I'm using the KentorIT library, at least I'm trying to. Can you give me a hint how to wire up the SAML2 library and Cookie Authentication?